# Creating a user control - ascx project so all web sites in the solution will use in vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish, ascx

i am looking for easy way to make my ascx files code in one place and all my web sites in the solution to use , using vs 2010 .
so if i make a changes in the ascx file rebuild\publish and all the depended websites will use the new version

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share controls between web sites you need to implement custom server control.

[Walkthrough: Developing and Using a Custom Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx)

User controls (ascx) are not supposed to be shared between web sites.

Although you can reference the same physical file from different projects, this is a bad approach.